# SD memory card causes BSOD on Windows when inserted

Tags: windows, bsod, sd-card

An Asus Eee PC netbook started to get BSOD blue stop screen with ntfs.sys stated in its error message.

I found out that the cause of BSOD is a **[Transcend SD 16 GB flash memory card](http://www.transcend-info.com/products/Catlist.asp?LangNo=0&modno=377)** (similar to this on the link) which was inserted in the netbook. When I insert this memory card into any other PC its Windows immediately crashes and reboots. I've tested both on Windows XP desktop and Windows 7 notebook. Windows Live CD also crashes with ntfs.sys error, similar to this:

> STOP: 0x00000024 (0x001902FE, 0xF7947814, 0xF7947510, 0xF7212167)
>   NTFS.SYS - address F7212167 base at F7205000  Datestamp 48025be5

Windows XP installation also fails.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubuntu live CD successfully opened this flash card. I've deleted such folders from card:

> System Volume Information
>
> RECYCLER
>
> PFiles

After that Windows XP successfully opened this flash card. I used `chkdsk H: /F /R /X` command . Some files were deleted and restored. Now this memory card works correctly.

Comment: You should consider marking this as an answer then :)

Comment: Yes, but I can't accept it because 2 days limit.

Answer (score 2):

`STOP error 0x24` means a problem occurred in `ntfs.sys`, the driver file that allows the system to read and write to NTFS drives.

If you're sure that the flash memory card is the cause of errors, then the FS on that card is corrupted and causing the trouble. Try mounting it to some Linux OS and repartition it. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Access the card from Linux LiveCD like ubuntu?